# How can I set values of external properties while creating new object

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm new to ASP.NET and for the start I want to make simple web app for movie store.
I created `Movie`, `Director`, `Actor` classes etc. and I want to add director and some actors while I'm creating new `Movie` object.
Here is my `Movie` model:

```
public class Movie {

    public Movie() { }

    public int MovieID { get; set; }
    public String Title { get; set; }
    public int Rating { get; set; }
    public int Price { get; set; }
    public virtual Director Director { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Actor> Actors { get; set; }

}
```

Here is my controller (the `Create` part):

```
        // GET: Movies/Create
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        ViewBag.DirectorsList = db.Directors.ToList();
        ViewBag.ActorsList = db.Actors.ToList();
        return View();
    }

    // POST: Movies/Create
    // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
    // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "MovieID,Title,Price")] Movie movie)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Movies.Add(movie);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(movie);
    }
```

And here is part of my view where I create `DropDownList` to choose director for a movie (actors works the same way):

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Director, new SelectList(ViewBag.DirectorsList, "DirectorID", "Name"))
```

So my problem is I don't really know how do I set Director and Actors property while creating a new movie. I tried adding "Director, Actors" to Bind, but doesn't work.

Comment: You cannot bind a dropdownlist to a complex object (`Director`) - you need to bind to a value type. Use a view model with a property(say) `int SelectedDirector` and use `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedDirector, new SelectList(.....))` (and your view model should also contain `IEnumerable<SelectListItem> DirectorsList` to avoid the use of `ViewBag`

Comment: ViewModel is the answer, thanks for help, now it works as expected :)